# Do I need an "it" in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, syntax, ellipsis

> The wrappers can be used to gather information from similar websites and integrate **[it]** into an XML document.

Does *integrate* necessarily need to be followed by "it" in this sentence?

Comment: Yes, you do need an object for the verb *integrate*, since the wrappers are not integrating themselves (reflexively) into the XML document.

Comment: An argument can also be made that because there is more than one wrapper, the correct word should be **them** instead of **it**

Comment: @BlackpoolTowr (+1) I think the "them" represent information which is uncountable. Am I right ? .... to gather and integrate ...

Comment: @BlackpoolTowr "it" refers to information

Comment: @Cardinal by "it" I mean information, should I use "them" for information?

Comment: I do not sure about it, but i thought that you have different information that should be integrated in something. But,  as I have search, I can see information is always in singular.

Comment: I think the correct object is "it"

Comment: Agree with TRomano. I would personally write it as: "and assemble/merge/integrate the gathered information (selectively?) into ...". (The choice of the verb would reflect the nuances of how such a XML document is made.)

Comment: I think you meant "succeeded by" or "followed by" rather than "preceded by".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need "it".

> The wrappers can be used to gather information from similar websites
>   and integrate **it** into an XML document.

*The wrappers gather information from websites and integrate **the information**  into the XML document.*

The implications otherwise are:

> The wrappers can be used to gather information from similar websites
>   and integrate into an XML document.

*The wrappers gather information from websites and integrate **themselves (i.e. the wrappers)** into the XML document.*

> The wrappers can be used to gather information from similar websites
>   and integrate **them** into an XML document.

*The wrappers gather information from websites and integrate **the websites** into the XML document.*